# Steps to create dag in airflow by connecting to remote database

Tags: oracle, airflow

I am learning airflow and I have to create a dag that will connect to a remote oracle database and insert data from one table to another. Below is what I have done till now

1. After installation, ran `pip install 'apache-airflow[oracle]'` so that I can use oracle operator
2. Created connection string from UI to connect to remote database
3. Then I wrote my first dag but it didn't seem to run.

Before I try to find why it's not running, I want to make sure if I have to do some other steps that I may have skipped like some changes in `airflow.cfg` file especially in `sql_alchemy_conn` (this file I found in my home directory) or if `cx_oracle` is required to be installed so that I can connect to remote database or just connection string is needed (step 2 above).

There are so many things mentioned about airflow but yet not clear on the exact steps. If someone could help me in this that will be much appreciated. These might be the basics but I am stuck with what to do from end to end. Please help

Thank you!!